# Hue service crashes when node runs out of RAM

Tags: hadoop, memory-management, bigdata, cloudera, hue

We have a 4 node cluster with Hue 3.9.0 installed. Namenode has 24 GB of RAM and each DataNode has 20 GB. We have several jobs running consuming resources:

- 15/24 GB (NameNode)
- 14/20 GB (DataNode)
- 13/20 GB (DataNode)
- 6/20 GB (DataNode)

We also run queries in Impala and Hive. Time after time those queries consume all available RAM (on NameNode) which everytime causes Hue to crash. When it happens Cloudera Manager (CM) shows Hue health as bad (process status: "Bad : This role's process exited. This role is supposed to be started.") while all the other services such as HBase, HDFS, Impala, Hive and so on have good health. After restarting Hue service via CM it works fine again. How can we prevent Hue from crashing because of lack of RAM?

I think what I am looking for is a means (option) to reserve enough RAM space for Hue service, but all I could find so far were Impala configuration options set via Hue configuration tab (with our current values in brackets):

1. Impala Daemon Memory Limit (mem_limit):

   - Impala Daemon Default Group (1701 MB)
   - Impala Daemon Group 1 (2665 MB)
2. Java Heap Size of Impala Llama ApplicationMaster in Bytes (2 GB)

But anyway running a sequence of queries (parallelly or one after another) eventually consumes all available RAM. It seems that it doesn't free RAM after a query is done. I'd rather expect Impala and Hive to say that they don't have enough RAM to continue and not crash other services such as Hue in this case.

Comment: Hue is a Python app. Heap size cannot be allocated for it. Why is Hue on the same server as the master services anyway? If you don't want it to crash, then relocate it to its own dedicated host